# Execute a random script in a folder

Tags: linux, command

I need to run a random script in a folder. I can use 'ls -1 /home/sepinto/EML-Samples/scripts/regular | sort -R | head -1' to get a random file name but how can I execute it?

Thanks

I can use 'ls -1 /home/sepinto/EML-Samples/scripts/regular | sort -R | head -1' to get a random file name but how can I execute it?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the shell you are using.
I will assume your shell is bash or sh and the scripts are already executable.

Then all you need to do is enclose your command line above in [backticks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtick).
Everything you type between backticks is evaluated (executed) by the shell and then replaced by the command's output.

```
`ls -1 /home/sepinto/EML-Samples/scripts/regular | sort -R | head -1`
```

**Edit:**
Turns out that the path is stripped if ls -1 is piped into another command.
A solution is to store the path in a variable so you can use it twice:

```
d="/home/sepinto/EML-Samples/scripts/regular"; $d/`ls -1 $d/ | sort -R | head -1`
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm using bash. I tried "sh `ls -1 /home/sepinto/EML-Samples/scripts/regular | sort -R | head -1`" but it didn't work. neither "bash `ls -1 /home/sepinto/EML-Samples/scripts/regular | sort -R | head -1`"

lets say `ls -1 /home/sepinto/EML-Samples/scripts/regular | sort -R | head -1` returns "abc.sh" how can I run it?

Comment: This will not work, as `ls` is executed on the directory and will return the filenames without path.

Answer (score 0):

First, change your ls command to list the files with complete path, then just execute them either directly with backticks or storing them in a variable.

```
SCRIPTNAME=`ls -1 /home/sepinto/EML-Samples/scripts/regular/*.sh | sort -R | head -1`
echo "Executing $SCRIPTNAME"
"$SCRIPTNAME"
```

The above assumes that all your files have a .sh ending, change the `ls` argument if this is not the case.